# BeautifulSoup/Scrapy: different BeautifulSoup html from Source HTML viewed in Firefox

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm new to both Python, BeautifulSoup, and Scrapy, so I'm not 100% sure how to describe the problem I'm having.

I'd like to scrape the url provided by the 'next' button you can see [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJROF.png), it's in-line next to the image links 'tiff' or 'jpeg'.

The issue is that the 'next' (and in subsequent pages, the 'previous') links don't seem to present themselves via the url I provide to scrapy. When I asked a friend to check the [url](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/collection/fsa/item/2017720833/resource/), she told me she didn't see the links. I confirmed this by printing the bs object associated with the tag id 'desciption':

`description = soup.find('div', {'id':'description'} )`

Because I generate this page from a search at the LOC website, I'm thinking I must need to pass something to my spider to indicate the search parameters. I tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069854/scrapy-how-to-set-referer-url), by changing the referer, but it still doesn't work:

```
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
        'Referer': 'www.loc.gov/pictures/collection/fsa/search/?co=fsa&amp;q=1935&amp;st=grid'
        }
```

I get the following output logs when I run my spider, confirming the referrer has been updated:

```
2018-07-31 15:41:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.loc.gov/robots.txt> (referer: www.loc.gov/pictures/collection/fsa/search/?co=fsa&amp;q=1935&amp;st=grid)
2018-07-31 15:41:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.loc.gov/pictures/resource/fsa.8a07028/?co=fsa> (referer: www.loc.gov/pictures/collection/fsa/search/?co=fsa&amp;q=1935&amp;st=grid)
```

If someone could help, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, that site uses sessions to store history of your search server-side.

The search is initiated from a URL like [yours](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/collection/fsa/search/?co=fsa&q=1935&st=grid).

But when visiting the image URLs afterwards, your session is active (via your cookies), and the site renders next / back links. If no session is found it doesn't (but you can still see the page). You can prove this by deleting your cookies after the initial search and watch it disappear when you refresh...

You'll need to tell Scrapy to first go the search URL, and then spider the results , making sure [cookie middleware is enabled](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-manage-cookies-automatically).