# How to make the website believe that the request is coming from a browser using Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, crawlera

I am trying to scrape this url:

```
https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-06-03/a-tesla-collapse-would-boost-european-carmakers-bernstein-says
```

I just wanted to scrape title and posted date only but bloomberg always banned man and think that I am robot

Sample Response that I've received:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bloomberg - Are you a robot?</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Any idea how can I make the website believe that the request is coming from a browser using Scrapy?

This is what I've done so far

```
  def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-05-30/tesla-dealt-another-blow-as-barclays-sees-it-as-niche-carmaker',
        headers={'X-Crawlera-Session': 'create',
                'Referrer': "https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-05-30/tesla-dealt-another-blow-as-barclays-sees-it-as-niche-carmaker",
                'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
                'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,ro;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6,la;q=0.5,pt;q=0.4,de;q=0.3',
                'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
                'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
        },

 def parse_sub(self, response):
     print(response.text)
```

I also use crawlera as well and I added it on settings.py

```
 DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'scrapy_crawlera.CrawleraMiddleware': 300}
 CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32
 CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 32
 AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = False
 DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 600
 CRAWLERA_APIKEY = 'API_KEY'
```

Please help me thank you

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069854/scrapy-how-to-set-referer-url

Comment: I think your best bet is Splash _without_ Crawlera.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `headers`, mainly to specify a `User-Agent` which tells the website general information about the browser and device. There is a massive [User-Agent List](https://github.com/cvandeplas/pystemon/blob/master/user-agents.txt) on GitHub if you need help finding one.

You can specify `headers` for a specific `request` like this:

```
yield Request(parse=..., headers={"User-Agent":"user_agent", "Referrer":"url_here", etc.})
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering my question but no luck still I get banned on the website

Comment: @ChristianRead did you turn off obey `robots.txt` in Scrapy config?

Comment: Hi @AeroBlue yes I already did turn off obey in robots.txt :)